# Could dark energy be a net repulsion from virtual colour-charged particles popping in and out of existence?

Tags: quarks, dark-energy, virtual-particles

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy Dark Energy makes up 68% of "universal density" as the article expresses it.

If there is a margin of error in that percentage which would allow the true value to be 66.66..% then that is two thirds of the total density. But on hearing talk of thirds, one (or at least I) immediately think of quark colour charges.

So could it be that colour-charged virtual quarks popping in and out of existence somehow produce the required net energy which manifests itself as Dark Energy, in a way that electrically charged virtual particles presumably do not (perhaps because their interactions are long range) ?

The simple answer is very likely "No", or else someone would have long since thought of it. But I'd be interested to hear expert opinions.

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect it would be the case, apart from the number 3? (the same kind of logic that would lead some people to conclude the standard model is the devil because 666)

Comment: I can't wait to hear what you think determines the fraction of non-dark-energy mass that goes to dark matter.

Comment: Virtual particles are no particles in the sense that they are mathematical artifacts.